# Write to CSV, duplicate key, different value

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to write to CSV from a dictionary that has list as its values.  I can get a print statement to work, but for some reason mysql will not accept the file from time to time. So I was trying to use `csv.writer`, but I cannot get the layout the way I need it.

Data Structure:

```
{'dillbill.grp': ['dillbiii', 'dilljt', 'dilltrst', 'dillwren', 'dillwind', 'dillgeor', 'dillgind', 'dillthom', 'dillells'], 'zgrptest.grp': ['dillbiii', 'dilljt', 'dilltrst', 'dillwren', 'dillwind', 'dillgeor', 'dillgind', 'dillthom', 'dillells', 'achfdn']}
```

Results from my print statement and what I would like for the `csv.writer` to do.

[image: Layout from Print Statement]

This is my print code and is how I would like `csv.writer` to structure the data:

```
with open('groups_old.csv','w', encoding='UTF8', newline='') as datacsv:
    for key, values in dicto.items():
        for v in values:
            print(key,',',v, file=datacsv)
    datacsv.close()
```

My `csv.writer` code.

```
with open('groups.csv','w') as datacsv:
    writer=csv.writer(datacsv)
    for keys in dicto.items():
        writer.writerows(key)  
        writer.writerows(values)
```

Comment: In your "print" code you concatenate key and value: `print(key,',',v, file=datacsv)` but in the "writer" you don't - you write key to a row, then values to a row

Comment: I have tried to concatenate in the writerrows code, but I cannot figure out how to do this. I used str() but since my values are in a list it did not like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the example from the csv [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html):

```
import csv
with open('eggs.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    spamwriter.writerow(['Spam'] * 5 + ['Baked Beans'])
    spamwriter.writerow(['Spam', 'Lovely Spam', 'Wonderful Spam'])
```

So if we apply this to your code it should be something like:

```
import csv

dicto = {
    'dillbill.grp': [
        'dillbiii', 'dilljt', 'dilltrst',
        'dillwren', 'dillwind', 'dillgeor',
        'dillgind', 'dillthom', 'dillells'],
    'zgrptest.grp': [
        'dillbiii', 'dilljt', 'dilltrst',
        'dillwren', 'dillwind', 'dillgeor',
        'dillgind', 'dillthom', 'dillells', 'achfdn']
}

with open('groups.csv','w', newline='') as datacsv:
    writer=csv.writer(datacsv)
    for key, value in dicto.items():
        for listitem in value:
            writer.writerow([key, listitem])
```

Result:

```
|------------| -------|
|dillbill.grp|dillbiii|
|dillbill.grp|dilljt  |
|dillbill.grp|dilltrst|
|. . .       |. . .   |
|zgrptest.grp|dillthom|
|zgrptest.grp|dillells|
|zgrptest.grp|achfdn  |
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked. I will take a look at the documentation again too. writerow vs writerows kept throwing me off.